# Validation with Joi in Axios call not giving correct response

Tags: node.js, validation, vue.js, axios, joi

I'm trying to apply validation with Joi on a NodeJS server and my frontend is Vue.
This is my backend validation function (in the AuthenticationPolicy):

```
    register(req, res, next) {
        const schema = Joi.object({
            email: Joi.string().email(),
            password: Joi.string().required()
        })
        const result = schema.validate(req.body)
        if (result.error) {
            console.log(`There was an error: ${JSON.stringify(result.error.details)}`)
            res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(result.error.details))
        }
        else {
            next()
        }
    }
```

This is the hanlder for the registration:

```
var authenticationPolicy = require('./policies/AuthenticationPolicy')
router.post('/register', authenticationPolicy.register, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Entered registration on server after validation`)
    res.send(`Registered! ${req.body.email}`)
})
```

When I try to enter an invalid Email the server logs:

```
There was an error: [{"message":"\"email\" must be a valid email","path":["email"],"type":"string.email","context":{"value":"Mailmailmail","key":"email","label":"email"}}]
POST /register 400 43.382 ms - 151
```

This is the relevant part in the frontend:
Service:

```
    register(credentials) {
        return Api().post('/register', credentials) //Api is the axios created to my baseURL
    }
```

Method in component:

```
            async register() {
                try {
                    this.error = null;
                    await AuthenticationService.register({
                        email: this.email,
                        password: this.password

                    })

                }
                catch (err) {

                    console.log(`${err.message}`)
                    this.error = err.message
                }
            }
```

When I run this with an invalid Email (mailmail) the browser logs `Request failed with status code 400`. Why doesn't the `err.message` That I log on the front end match the response I get from the backend? If I understand correctly, Axios rejected the promise because of the 400 status so it was thrown, but where did the body go?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

So after many hours of debugging and playing around, I realized that the `err` object that I catch is an object whose structure I didn't know. Specifically, it has a response component. `err.response.data` got me what I want.
I would still like to know if anyone has any ideas how could I find something like this out, I didn't see anything that pointed me in this direction in the documentation and I guess the logging wasn't what I expected.

Comment: Yes, thats tricky. Here is a good example: https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors